# CodeWars Are they the same question swift

Tags: swift

Question :

> Given two arrays `a` and `b`, write a function `comp(a, b) (orcompSame(a, b))` that checks whether the two arrays have the "same" elements, with the same multiplicities (the multiplicity of a member is the number of times it appears). "Same" means, here, that the elements in `b` are the elements in `a` square, regardless of the order.
>
> **Examples**
>
> *Valid arrays*
> `a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]`
> `b = [121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]`
> `comp(a, b)` returns true because in `b` 121 is the square of 11, 14641 is the square of 121, 20736 the square of 144, 361 the square of 19, 25921 the square of 161, and so on. It gets obvious if we write `b`'s elements in terms of squares:
>
> `a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]`
> `b = [11*11, 121*121, 144*144, 19*19, 161*161, 19*19, 144*144, 19*19]`
>
> *Invalid arrays*
> If, for example, we change the first number to something else, `comp` is not returning true anymore:
> `a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]`
> `b = [132, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]`
> `comp(a,b)` returns false because in `b` 132 is not the square of any number of `a`.
>
> `a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]`
> `b = [121, 14641, 20736, 36100, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]`
> `comp(a,b)` returns false because in `b` 36100 is not the square of any number of `a`.

My answer is:

```
import SwiftUI
        
func comp(_ a: [Int], _ b: [Int]) -> Bool {
    var value = false
    let aSorted = a.sorted()
    let bSorted = b.sorted()
      for i in 0...a.count-1 {
          if a.count == b.count && aSorted[i] * aSorted[i] == bSorted[i] {
            value = true
        }
        else {
          value = false
        }
       }
  return value
}
```

Kata says my answer is wrong but I tried this code with different arrays and it works fine. Can anybody say where is the error in my code thank you?

Comment: You should exit after the first `value = false`. Because you don't, you may overwrite it to `true` on the next iteration.

Comment: Also, for optimlization, you could check beforehand the size of `a` & `b` before doing the for loop, and even before the `sorted()`.. Because you are doing it each time in the for loop, but the test will always be the same.

Comment: To illustrate @GSerg comment what about testing [1,2] & [3, 4]? Because currently, your code will return `true` if the arrays are of the same size and the last element of the second one is the square of the last element of the first one.

Comment: func comp(_ a: [Int], _ b: [Int]) -> Bool {
    var value: Bool
    
    if a.count == b.count {
        value = true
    }
    
    else {
        value = false
    }
    
    let aSorted = a.sorted()
    let bSorted = b.sorted()
    
   
    for i in 0...a.count-1 {
        if aSorted[i] * aSorted[i] == bSorted[i] {
            continue
        }
        else {
          value = false
        }
       }
    return value
} I updated this code and it pass test however ı encounter problem with kata test

Comment: Could you edit your question with the new code? It's hard to reed in comment? I And what's the Kata error? Which test are you failing?

Comment: If b.count != a.count, the value is set first at false. But then you enter the for loop, and you might crash (because the size is different). But, in case of b size being bigger than a size, it doesn't crash. And, then, `value` might  be set to `true` while it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reimplement [the `==` operator for `Array`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift). You don't need to do that.

```swift
func comp<Numbers: Sequence>(_ a: Numbers, _ b: Numbers) -> Bool
where Numbers.Element: Numeric & Comparable {
  a.sorted().map(\.squared) == b.sorted()
}
```

```swift
public extension Numeric {
  var squared: Self { self * self }
}
```

Comment: It's interesting response, but I think that it might be to high level for the user, since he/she is learning coding, and can't debug his/her current issue.